# Enumeration that includes WEEKS, MONTHS, YEARS

Tags: java

I would like to use an enum that includes WEEKS, MONTHS, YEARS.

The [`java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) enum only goes up to [DAYS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#DAYS). Is such an enum defined in the java language?

Comment: you mean something like this? Since 'YEARS' is not a limited amount, I don't see any benefit of creating an Enum for this.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/enum.html

Comment: Java have strong dualism with date/time philosophy:1. independent time (aka astronomical) 2. date in culture, and cultures have 13mth year etc ..., maybe some exotic cultures with decade concept (?) instead week, your question must have good background

Comment: @Stultuske: As per assylias's answer, `ChronoUnit` is such an enum, and it can make perfect sense when used in the right context.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes. I was looking in the context of year = '2016' and not year = '12 months'. in that context, it didn't really make sense to me :)

Answer (score 5):

You could use [ChronoUnit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) - it even goes as high as CENTURIES and ERAS.